# SignalR: Unable to get value of the property 'start': object is null or undefined

Tags: signalr

I am getting error while i call start on SignalR connection object.

I am utilizing singalr functionality in a plain HTML page.

Below is the peace of code included in the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.2.js"></script>
<script src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'type="text/javascript"></script
```

`var movieTicketHub = $.connection.movieTicketHub;`

$(
            function () {

```
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }
    );
```

This is my hub

```
namespace MovieReservation
```

{
    public class MovieTicketHub:Hub
    {
        public void BookTicket(string no, bool booked)
        {
            Clients.SendNotification(no, booked);
        }
    }
}

Error Message: Unable to get value of the property 'start': object is null or undefined

Comment: did you include jquery twice on the page?

Comment: No. its only included once in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way dynamic signalR javascript referred.
below change solved my problem.

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```